# callback before_save seems not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need execute the method name before the record is saved in the database, but it seems not working

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :checkins
  validates_presence_of :FirstName
  validates_presence_of :LastName
  validates_format_of :FirstName, with: /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/
  validates_format_of :LastName, with: /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/

  def name
    self.FirstName.titleize  + " " + self.LastName.titleize  
  end
end
```

console

```
=> Guest(id: integer, FirstName: string, LastName: string, age: integer, sex: string, photo: string, address: text, mobile: integer, email: string, birthdate: date, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime) 
1.9.3-p547 :008 > f=Guest.new
 => #<Guest id: nil, FirstName: nil, LastName: nil, age: nil, sex: nil, photo: nil, address: nil, mobile: nil, email: nil, birthdate: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p547 :009 > f.FirstName=" fernando "
 => " fernando " 
1.9.3-p547 :010 > f.LastName=" suarez"
 => " suarez" 
1.9.3-p547 :011 > f.save
 => true 
1.9.3-p547 :012 > Guest.last
 => #<Guest id: 9, FirstName: " fernando ", LastName: " suarez", age: nil, sex: nil, photo: nil, address: nil, mobile: nil, email: nil, birthdate: nil, created_at: "2015-04-26 00:16:38", updated_at: "2015-04-26 00:16:38">
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Because in the database  the record should be  FirstName: "Fernando" not  "fernando" or I have that modify the setters

Comment: Please for the question . I have that to modify the setters

Comment: It is not a good idea to titleize names and validate names against simple regexp. Nice read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Spickermann how can I improve my code. I am a newbie at this

Comment: Not everybody has a first and a lastname, not every name start with an upcase character, not every culture understands, what you mean by first or lastname, people might have names with characters not in your regexp... I suggest to just have a one field `name` and allow the user to enter whatever fits best in his culture.

Comment: thanks spicker but is a schoolar proyect that accept only names in Spanish. Thanks a lot for your advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
self.FirstName.titleize  + " " + self.LastName.titleize
```

to

```
self.FirstName = self.FirstName.titleize
self.LastName  = self.LastName.titleize
```

Explanation: You didn't actually change anything, but concatenate the values.

But probably you want to use the `name` method for your name-representation. So I'd suggest a new method for the validation.

It would look like this:

```
def titlelize_names
  self.FirstName = self.FirstName.titleize
  self.LastName  = self.LastName.titleize
end
```

And the before_save must call `:titlelize_names`, of course.

Comment: Andreas I need the method name self.FirstName.titleize  + " " + self.LastName.titleize in the controller for to use it after

Comment: Andreas that callback method you recommend me to use

Comment: Stay on it. It's a great thing. ;-)